# Returning a HTTP response data from a function in a multithreaded manner (C# / VB )

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, http, webrequest

I know about the `IAsyncResult` approach, however from my experimentation this still momentarily freezes the UI a little - which is weird to me. I've Google'd a lot and I cannot seem to find a way to implement this that does not freeze the UI a little.

What I want is for a function to return data from a `HttpWebReqeust` in a threaded manner. I need a good way to do this, and not threading it, and then setting some variable to `true` and storing the response in a shared variable.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful

Comment: I understand - however, the code is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've mentioned from the MSDN **do block the UI** because of these lines:

```
Thread.Sleep(0);
Console.WriteLine("Main thread {0} does some work.",
    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

// Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

You can see here a blocking wait for a execution to be complete. So for a `async` way to get the `HttpResponse` you can easily use the `async/await` keywords, with [dozens of the sample code](http://jessemon.blogspot.com/2014/05/c-async-httpwebrequest-console-poc.html):

```
// inside the method marked as async
// prepare the Web Request
Task<WebResponse> getResponseTask = req.GetResponseAsync();
WebResponse response = await getResponseTask;
// process your result in the same context which have fired the request
```